# Birt report viewer and internationalization

Tags: internationalization, viewer, birt

I'm trying to internationalize some titles in Birt. I'm using Birt report viewer and simply used a birt tag in my jsp to display my report.

It worked nice until I tried to internationalize some titles. I created a resource.properties file with my key=value association. My rptdesign is set to version 3.2.23 instead of 3.2 once I have referenced my key.

Next, I get the following error when my jsp is loaded :

```
The file reporting.rptdesign has error and can not be run.
```

Hence I would like to know if there are some specific jars required for internationalization using the report viewer.

Edit : the problem seems to be independant of internationalization itself. Simply changing the version to 3.2.23 makes an error. I tried to put a later version like 3.2.6 but each time I reference a key, the version is set back to 3.2.23 as if it was the only version taking internationalization into account !

Edit 2 : I deployed the WebViewerExample of Birt Runtime 4.2 and could use an rptdesign of version 3.2.23 in it.  The internationalization doesn't seem to work for moment, but I guess it's not the same error now... Will add an answer once I get everything to work using the birt tag.

Edit 3 : It works in the Eclipse preview, but not once deployed in a tomcat. I have tried several changes to the web.xml and the location of the resources, but did not change. However the web.xml is read since I can change the locale in it and see the internationalized messages of the birt core. But my specific key/value associations are not taken into account.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem and added some information on this other post :

[Birt internationalization doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613450/birt-internationalization-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

You can do internationalization in BIRT,

You have to add ".properties" files to Resources in ".rptdesign" and the select what ever title(Eg:label) you want to internationalization click the Localization properties add the key value from the .properties files, I have done this with 3.7 and 4.2 its working nicely,

But there is a problem when we exporting to PDF format still i couldn't find the solution to that

Hope this will help you

Cheers

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Some can please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28578243/how-to-assign-the-birt-report-rptdesign-file-to-jsp